# CruiseControl.Net NUnit results not showing up in dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a new cc.net server and am trying to get the nunit results to show up on the dashboard.

The results ARE being written to the buildlog.xml file but there is no output on the dashboard.

The docs for the merge task state:

- Click the original log link and check
  to see if the merged content is
  included in the xml. If it is missing
  then got onto step 2. If it is
  present and is still not showing up
  in the web page then try emailing the
  CCNet users list.

I think that describes what I am seeing.

My Merge task looks just like the docs and my other servers:

```
     <publishers>
        <merge>
            <files>
                <file>.\*-NUnitResults.xml</file>
            </files>
        </merge>
        <xmllogger />
        <statistics />
        <modificationHistory onlyLogWhenChangesFound="true" />
    </publishers>
```

And the -NunitResults.xml files are definitely there.

Also I have configured the dashboard to enable Nunit Results.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't be like me and have a wrong path for the XML file: there will be no notification if it can't find the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the NUnit CC.net task you don't need to manually merge the results.
You say you have configured the dashboard to enable Nunit Results. Did you add the Nunit Details xsl file to the dashboard.config AND restart the whole IIS?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I had not set up the dashboard.config at all and that was the problem.